# PowerBI – Microsoft Teams Meetings Report

Tags: outlook, powerbi, office365, microsoft-teams

Does anyone know how to create a report in Power BI or any other reporting service that contains information of all my meetings run through Microsoft Teams, whether they are recurring or one–time, and the number of participants who joined that meeting? All my meetings are organized in Outlook through Office365; let me know if you can help; thanks!

Comment: The Microsoft Call Quality Dashboard (CQD) shows call and meeting quality, at an org-wide level, for Microsoft Teams, Skype for Business Online, and Skype for Business Server 2019. Currently it is only possible to use Power BI to analyze CQD data for Microsoft Teams https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/cqd-power-bi-query-templates.  You can raise a feature ask at [Microsoft Teams feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).